# ¿Cómo puedo descargar un archivo de excel que esta alojado en el servidor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Estoy usando este código para descargar pero no funciona :

```
   FileInfo File = new FileInfo(path);
       if (File.Exists)
       {
       Response.ClearContent();
       Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Contact.xls");
       Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
       Response.WriteFile(File.FullName);
       Response.End();
       }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! no funciona que quiere decir? usa el boton [edit] y aclara bien que pasa

Answer (score 0):

Vas bien, solo cambia los parámetros a enviar en Response.WriteFile

```
Response.WriteFile(path, 0, File.Length);
```